# Appium inspector - not able to inspect elements inside the flatlist/scrollview - iOS (react native) app

Tags: react-native, appium, ios-simulator, appium-ios, appium-inspector

I'm running the react native iOS app on simulator and wanted to inspect the elements using the appium and appium inspector. The appium inspector is showing only the flatlist/scrollview element but not the elements (Menu-0, Menu-1, etc) inside it.

Find the details and screenshot below.

appium version: 2.2.1

appium-inspector: 2023.10.4

Desired capabilities:

{

```
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 14 Pro",

"platformName": "iOS",

"appium:platformVersion": "16.2",

"appium:bundleId": "com.testapp.dev",

"appium:snapshotMaxDepth": 100000,

"appium:automationName": "XCUITest"
```

}

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APMXE.png

I have tried by giving access=false and true for the flatlist/scrollview but it didn't work.